# Animation within :target pseudo-element triggers only on the first click

Tags: css, css-animations, pseudo-class

I want to highlight some HTML element when another element is clicked. The classic solution with CSS only seems to go as follow, with the following HTML,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      There are <a href="#fermions">Fermions</a> 
      and <a href="#bosons">Bosons</a>.
      <div class="highlightable" id="fermions">
        Bosons are very social particles!
      </div>
      <div class="highlightable" id="bosons">
        Fermions only goes out as a couple!
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the following CSS

```
@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background: LightSkyBlue;
  }
  100% {
    background: none;
  }
}

.highlightable:target {
  animation: highlight 1s;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle implementing this](https://jsfiddle.net/ljbo3/745to6ex/). When I click on "Fermions", the `div` "Fermions only goes out as a couple!" highlights. Good! When I click again on "Fermions", it does not highlight anymore. But if I click on "Bosons", thus highlighting the other `div`, and then again on Fermions, then the `div` with Fermions hightlights again.

Could someone explain what is going on? Is the only solution to always have a click highlight the corresponding `div` to use Javascript?

Comment: because it already the target, so the animation is still there ... it's like you added a class then you want to add it again, but it's already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation of what you are seeing:

If your browser is currently pointing at this address:

```
mysite.com/mypage/
```

and you click on `<a href="#fermions">`, your browser will now point to:

```
mysite.com/mypage/#fermions
```

This will trigger the `:target` pseudo-class animation.

If you now click on `<a href="#fermions">` again... you won't go anywhere - because you're already there.

So the animation won't be triggered.

---

## Achieving this effect (CSS only):

I appreciate you probably want a CSS-only way to to produce this effect, but... you can only (sort-of) respond to user **clicks** via CSS using `:focus` and `:target`. In both cases, you'll see that once you have entered a given state (and the animation has run once) you will remain in that state (and the animation won't run again) until you pro-actively change the state.

That said, you *can* produce the effect you want by responding to user **mouse-overs** via CSS, using the `:hover` pseudo-class.

**Working Example:**

```css
[href="#fermions"]:hover ~ #fermions,
[href="#bosons"]:hover ~ #bosons {
animation: highlight 1.2s ease-out 0.15s;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  0% {background: LightSkyBlue;}
100% {background: none;}
}
```

```html
<div>
There are <a href="#fermions">Fermions</a> and <a href="#bosons">Bosons</a>.

<p class="highlightable" id="bosons">
Bosons are very social particles!</p>

<p class="highlightable" id="fermions">Fermions only goes out as a couple!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't agree a lot with the hover state as it will require a specific HTML structure : your elements need to be siblings, which is not easy to achieve in most of the cases

Comment: Yes, I acknowledge that. I think the only alternative is to use javascript. I would listen for an `onclick` event, add a class to trigger the animation and set a timeout, (fractionally longer than the duration of the animation) which then removes the class again, just after the animation is finished.

Comment: It would be difficult to reorganise the HTML indeed. Not only that but the highlighted div may be far enough from the clickable link that scrolling is necessary, which would not work well with hovering. But kudos for teaching me a nice trick!